# How can I make pyautogui wait for an image to appear, and then after it appears and an action is completed, wait for the next image to appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I've been using pyautogui to automate some browser stuff like so:

```
        time.sleep(1)
        locationscs = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('scs.PNG', confidence=.8)
        pyautogui.click(locationscs)
        time.sleep(1)
```

This is not ideal because sometimes, the page doesn't load in time and I don't make the click.

I've tried something like this:

```
        r = None
        while r is None:
            location3 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ii.PNG', confidence=.7)
            pyautogui.click(location3)
```

This will click on my element but then it just continues to click on it. I tried setting r to not none like so:

```
        r = None
        while r is None:
            location3 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ii.PNG', confidence=.7)
            pyautogui.click(location3)
            r = not None
```

This did not work and just crashed my script. Anyways, I have many more images to click on after this. How can I have pyautogui wait for image 1, click on it, then proceed to wait on image 2, click, then image 3, click?

What I tried is explained above.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
import time

#for first image

while True:
    time.sleep(1) #prevents lag and waits for new image
    image1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ii.PNG', confidence=.7)#first image location
    if image1: #if the image is found
        print('found image clicking...')
        pyautogui.click(image1)
        break

#for second image

while True:
    time.sleep(1) #prevents lag and waits for new image
    image2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ii.PNG', confidence=.7) #second image
    if image2: #if the image is found
        print('found image clicking...')
        pyautogui.click(image2)
        break

#and so on
```